# ElementTree XPath - Select Element based on attribute

Tags: python, elementtree

I am having trouble using the attribute XPath Selector in ElementTree, which I should be able to do according to the [Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20200703234507/http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm)

Here's some sample code

**XML**

```
<root>
 <target name="1">
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
 </target>
 <target name="2">
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
 </target>
</root>
```

**Python**

```
def parse(document):
    root = et.parse(document)
    for target in root.findall("//target[@name='a']"):
        print target._children
```

I am receiving the following Exception:

```
expected path separator ([)
```

Comment: Using ElementTree 1.2.6, the attribute xpath features are only available in 1.3 and beyond.

Comment: Looks like findall `only` supports a subset `XPath`. See the mailing list discussion [here](https://mailman-mail5.webfaction.com/pipermail/lxml/20060526/009219.html).

Comment: Why close this? It was useful for me... It is hardly off topic.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The syntax you're trying to use is new in **[ElementTree 1.3](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm)**.

Such version is shipped with **Python 2.7** or higher.
If you have Python 2.6 or less you still have ElementTree 1.2.6 or less.

Answer (score 34):

There are several problems in this code.

1. Python's buildin ElementTree (ET for short) has no real XPATH support; only a limited subset  By example, it doesn't support *find-from-root* expressions like `//target`.

   Notice: the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)
   mentions "**//**", but only for children: So an expression as
   `.//target` is valid; `//...` is not!

   There is an alternative implementation: [**lxml**](http://lxml.de) which is more rich. It's seams that documentation is used, for the build-in code. That does not match/work.
2. The `@name` notation selects xml-**attributes**; the `key=value` expression within an xml-tag.

   So that name-value has to be 1 or 2 to select something in the given document. Or, one can search for targets with a child **element** *'a'*: `target[a]` (no @).

For the given document, parsed with the build-in ElementTree (v1.3) to root, the following code is correct and working:

- `root.findall(".//target")`    Find both targets
- `root.findall(".//target/a")`  Find two a-element
- `root.findall(".//target[a]")` This finds both target-element again, as both have an a-element
- `root.findall(".//target[@name='1']")` Find only the *first* target. Notice the quotes around 1 are needed; else a SyntaxError is raised
- `root.findall(".//target[a][@name='1']")` Also valid; to find that target
- `root.findall(".//target[@name='1']/a")` Finds only one a-element; ...