# How to select data for xml Element with specific attribute value?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

Given:

```
<foo>
 <bar key="true">text1</bar>
 <bar key="false">text2</bar>
 <bar key="true">text3</bar>
 <bar key="true">text4</bar>
</foo>
```

I want to get the text for the bar element where the key attribute = "false".

My application is Python 2.5.5 on GAE.  The XML is not true xml, but I can load it as an ElementTree and fetch data normally.

Code example:

```
result = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
xml = ElementTree.fromstring(result)
str = xml.find("./bar").attrib['key']
```

to get the first value.  I've tried various xpath queries that I think should work but I've obviously got the syntax wrong.

UPDATE:

```
str = xml.findtext("./bar[@key='false']")
```

Throws error:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 93, in __init__
    "expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)
SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)
```

Comment: findtext seems like an odd way of using xpath, especially considering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python shows a different method.

Comment: Merydith: Please, use a full complain XPath engine like `lxml` and not basic ElementTree API.

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong but I dont think that the "`./bar[@key='false']`" notation works in Python 2.5.5 (or at least not with the ElementTree that comes with it).  I have observed the same problem in Python 2.6.5, but it does work in Python 2.7.1.  I guess you will have to use another library or try the "experimental" GAE with Python 2.7.

Comment: Looking at the source of ElementTree as included with Python 2.5, it does seem that attribute selectors aren't supported.

Answer (score 2):

This XPath will select the `bar` nodes whose `key` attribute is equal to `false`:

```
/foo/bar[@key='false']
```

If the current context node is the `foo` node then this will also work:

```
./bar[@key='false']
```

Comment: I thought that was the syntax, but it returns and error (see update to original post).

Comment: @Will Merydith - Are you sure the current context node is `foo`? Try the first example.

Comment: I'm pretty certain because the rest of my code is working (grabbing lots of data from this xml).  If I try the first example I get the error: "SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element"

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222375/elementtree-xpath-select-element-based-on-attribute), the XPath selector functionality was not implemented in ElementTree until version 1.3, which ships with Python 2.7, as [@cdemers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038432/cdemers) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8421523/470925).

Answer (score 0):

"[@attrib]" which you are using is only introduced in ElementTree 1.3:
http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm

which was introduced only to Python 2.7:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

As other people here mentioned, you need to get this attribute differently or upgrade Python for that code to work.