# updating python-elementtree to overcome xpath selector issue

Tags: python, package, apt, aptitude

I'm getting an error when searching for the attribute of a node in my xml using ElementTree.

```
expected path separator ([)
```

The source code is:

```
home_team_node = game_node.find( "team/team-metadata[@alignment='home']" )
```

This discussion on Stackoverflow leads me to conclude I need a newer version of ElementTree.

[ElementTree XPath - Select Element based on attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222375/elementtree-xpath-select-element-based-on-attribute)

When I list installed packages I see I have python-elementtree version 1.2.6-14. Yet even after running apt-get update, any effort to upgrade python-elementtree tells me I've got the latest version. I'm running Ubuntu 9.10, so maybe the repositories don't have elementtree 1.3.

What can I do to upgrade to version 1.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/)  is a very useful library for parsing XML, and it has a complete implementation of the ElementTree API.  Try installing it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

You'll then need to [change your import statments](http://lxml.de/compatibility.html) to use the lxml version instead of the bundled `elementree`.

(I would resist using `pip` or `easy_install` unless you're in a `virtualenv` environment, to avoid confusion with the Debian-packaged Python libraries.)

Comment: Be warned that building/installing lxml in a reliable cross-platform way can be quite a problem, especially on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing lxml, ElementTree or cElementTree with either `easy_install` or `pip`. These packages are likely more recent than the ones in the `apt` repositories.

HTH

Comment: easy_install elementtree produced: Searching for elementtree
Best match: elementtree 1.2.7-20070827-preview
Processing elementtree-1.2.7_20070827_preview-py2.6.egg
elementtree 1.2.7-20070827-preview is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/elementtree-1.2.7_20070827_preview-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for elementtree
Finished processing dependencies for elementtree

Comment: pip install --upgrade elementree also got me 1.2.7